# Checkboxes to select objects in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have Article model and user wants to select which articles should be exported to file.

I want to use Django Form / ModelForm class to generate something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="articles[0]">Article #0</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="articles[1]">Article #1</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="articles[2]">Article #2</input>
<!-- ... -->
```

How can I do that and then get selected articles?

Comment: Can you show code you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's forms have a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) for that. The default widget is `<select>`, but you can tell it to use checkboxes instead ([`CheckboxSelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple)):

```
from django import forms
from <yourapp>.models import Article

class ExportForm(forms.Form):
     …
    articles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = Article.objects.all(), # or .filter(…) if you want only some articles to show up
        widget  = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )
```